# Input width not working on table display flex overflow hidden firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Inside an HTML table. I have an input with a display flex parent with a width. The input is overflow hidden. I get a different behavior between browsers. Chrome shrinks the input field to the width. Firefox does not.

If I put width:100% on the input it starts working on firefox but I would like to not add that style.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
}

.myInput {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div><input class="myInput" value="0.50"></div>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

EDIT:
Filed a bug with Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1882139

EDIT 2: They determined it was not a bug but the correct behaviour.

Comment: Am am sure if you used standard HTML `<div class="v-ctrcntr">` and CSS `.v-ctrcntr {` it would be just fine ..

Comment: @Zak, no same result. Made the change in my question.

Comment: Tested on Firefox and Chrome .. Both show input sticking to the `50px` width.

Comment: @Zac, what version are you using? I'm having the issue on FF 123.0.

Comment: Well on 121 .. It works .. On 123 it doesn't ..  Tried 2 different machines ..  Seems like a FF bug

Comment: @Zak, I filed a bug with FF. Thank you. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1882139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As stated in @ntr's comment this isn't a bug. As per current [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#form-controls) input overflow should be set to clip ([issue#9994](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/9994)) and therefore it should never be a scroll container. Use `min-width:0` is the best option here.

```css
input:not([type=image i], [type=range i], [type=checkbox i], [type=radio i]) {
  overflow: clip !important;
  overflow-clip-margin: 0 !important;
}
```

---

<s>I would say this is indeed a bug in FireFox 123 as the intended behavior is fully specified in the spec.</s>

As per [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto):

> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, the used value of a main axis automatic minimum size on a flex item that is not a scroll container is a content-based minimum size; **for scroll containers the automatic minimum size is zero**, as usual.

When you've set `overflow:hidden` on input box ( which is either by default `inline-block` or computed as `block` because of being under a flex container), it should be a scroll container [as per spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-hidden):

> 'hidden'
>
> This value indicates that the box’s content is clipped to its padding box and that the UA must not provide any scrolling user interface to view the content outside the clipping region, nor allow scrolling by direct intervention of the user, such as dragging on a touch screen or using the scrolling wheel on a mouse. However, the content must still be scrollable programmatically, for example using the mechanisms defined in [CSSOM-VIEW], **and the box is therefore still a scroll container**.

Hence `min-width:auto` should be handled as `min-width:0`. The following two example should behave the same:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overflow-h {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mw-0 {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><input class="input overflow-h" value="0.50"></div>
<div><input class="input mw-0" value="0.50"></div>
```

Of course, with neither `overflow:hidden` or `min-width:0` specified, it should respect the content size, which is the the `size` attribute (defaults to 20) of the text input plus some paddings.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div><input value="0.50" size=10></div>
<div><input value="0.50"></div>
<div><input value="0.50" size=100></div>
```

Comment: The bug I filed with FF was closed down. Saying the behaviour is normal. If you want to file another one or update mine, you are more than welcomed to: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1882139

Comment: Firefox are not budging. Here's the response I got: 
    <input> is always a replaced element, so not a scroll container.
    The main issue is that you're not setting overflow, since the !important rule I linked above overrides it. This is obvious if you toggle the "Show browser styles" option in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` needs to be on the parent element to hide the part of the input that overflows the parent's width.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div><input class="myInput" value="0.50"></div>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Addition after comments:

As I wrote, `overflow: hidden` (on the parent) will *cut off*  the contents, so the `input` element will only remain partly visible.

To get what you apparently want, you can apply `max-width: 100%;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `input`, which limits its width to the width of the parent and makes sute also the border remains visible, staying inside of / being included in those 100%.

BTW: `display: flex` on the `div` does actually nothing at all in this situation, so I erased it from this second snippet:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
}

.myInput {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div><input class="myInput" value="0.50"></div>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I get the same issue on FF 123. Input is cut off.

Comment: Of course it's cut off. `overflow: hidden` doesn't *shorten*  the content, it cuts it off (and thereby possibly makes part of it invisible).

Comment: That makes sense in theory but it works on all browsers even FF 121 except FF 123.

Comment: Then browsers handle it differently, but what I wrote is true, so you can rather not call it a FF bug, but only a different interpretation.